# Connect to local sql express database from my web application

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html

I need to add a feature to connect to local sql express database from my web app . Is these any option to make it from javascript , I can do that with html5 but It isn't supported on each browser.

Thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look this:

```
var connection = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection") ;

var connectionstring="Data Source=<server>;Initial Catalog=<catalog>;User ID=<user>;Password=<password>;Provider=SQLOLEDB";

connection.Open(connectionstring);
var rs = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");

rs.Open("SELECT * FROM table", connection);
rs.MoveFirst
while(!rs.eof)
{
   document.write(rs.fields(1));
   rs.movenext;
}

rs.close;
connection.close;
```

Comment: I have an error saying don't have a permission to connect the database when arrive to the line connection.Open(connectionstring);

Comment: set user permission on database server.  http://www.websense.com/content/support/library/web/v75/triton_web_help/permissions_3aSQL%20Server.aspx